# How can I display only errors when running dotnet watch run?

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface, blazor

My dotnet 6 project has several hundred warnings. And when I run `dotnet watch run` it shows all of those yellow warnings. And it does it every time Hot Reload applies a rude edit. How can I get it to suppress those warnings? I have tried `dotnet watch run --property:clp=ErrorsOnly` but that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`appsettings.json` & `appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```